# how to find the number of the first parameter of every list in a 3d matrix

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, multidimensional-array, printing

I have a 3d matrix:
grocery_list = [ [banana, 20], [oranges, 10], [grapes, 14] ]

How do I print the first element of every list in python.
I want the print to look like [banana, oranges, grapes] without the price

I tried: print(grocery_list[:][0], but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (list comprehension):

```
grocery_list = [ ["banana", 20], ["oranges", 10], ["grapes", 14] ]

print([x[0] for x in grocery_list])
```

result:

```
['banana', 'oranges', 'grapes']
```